# Bond: How to change field and class names during code generation

Tags: c#, bond

I have a bond file with a struct like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    0: float myField1;
    1: float myField2;
}
```

I am using this file to generate code for C++ and also for C#. But in the C# code, I want the field names to be capitalized: MyField1, MyField2.

Is there any way to do this?

Similarly, I might want Foo to be named Bar in my C# code (in order to be backward compatible with my pre-bond clients). But I don't see any documentation on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to rename types/fields when using the Bond code generator, gbc. The features simply don't exist.

If you want, you can write a C# class by hand and annotate it with Bond's [attributes](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#attributes). This will get you a *highly compatible* struct. You do lose much of the benefit of having one, central location to describe the structs in the .bond file with this approach. That might be the right trade off to interface with your pre-Bond clients by annotating the existing classes.

An example of how you'd do this based on the structs in the question:

```
[Bond.Schema]
class Bar
{
    [Bond.Id(0)]
    public float MyField1;

    [Bond.Id(1)]
    public float MyField2;
}
```

This has some caveats:

- You'll have to manually keep it in sync with the .bond file when you make changes.
- The full schemas of these Foo and Bar structs differ slightly. The fields have different names ("myField1" vs. "MyField2"), which you'll be able to detect if you look at the SchemaDef of each struct. When using [binary protocols](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#protocols), the field names don't matter: only the IDs do. When using the text-based protocols, [the names do matter](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#simple-json).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check this out and compare to my solution, which has similar problems: I created 2 .bond files, one for c++ and one for c#. They are almost identical except for capitalization and some particular fields that need conversion (e.g. TimeSpan). This solution also has the problem of keeping the files in sync. (I am using binary serialization, so the differences in names don't really bother me.)

Comment: If you're willing to have the same capitalization in C++ and C#, you can move to one .bond file. For a time span, an alias like `using TimeSpan = uint64` works in both [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/date_time) and [C++](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cpp/core/time_alias); you just give different options to gbc when generating code.